# Loop Interpolate and then update values

Tags: python, pandas, loops, interpolation

I have a dataset containing both timeseries and cross-sectional data. There are some missing columns that I want to handle through linear interpolation.

I tried this code but there was a caveat error that appeared. The code still worked but I'm just worried that it might not work after some time. Is there a better way to do this process?

```
for i in merged_df.country_code.unique():
   merged_df[merged_df.country_code == i].interpolate(inplace=True)
```

Error code below:

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as indicated in the doc, that `merged_df[merged_df.country_code == i]` is a part of your `merged_df`. Once you try to *chain* with with some inplace operations, pandas cannot guarantee the operations work on the original dataframe or a copy of it. It's safer to do a copy and reassign with `loc`:

```
for i in merged_df.country_code.unique():
    mask = merged_df.country_code == i
    merged_df.loc[mask] = merged_df.loc[mask].interpolate()
```

This is, IMHO, one of the reasons why `inplace=True` is not a good practice.

That said, in this case, you can bypass `for` loop with a `groupby`:

```
merge_df = merge_df.groupby('country_code').interpolate()
```

or:

```
merge_df = merge_df.groupby('country_code').apply(lambda x: x.interpolate())
```

Comment: yeah, i agree that inplace = True is a bit tricky. thanks a lot for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that pandas can't guarantee that the object that you're assigning the new data to is a temporary object or the correct object. Whilst it will probably work, it's better you use

```
merged_df.loc[merged_df["country_code"]==i,0].interpolate(inplace=True)
```

As this guarantees that you use the correct object.